# Given a function $f(x,y)$ d find $f(x,y)$ expressed by r and v

Tags: real-analysis

Given the function

$$
f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2} \ \ \ & \text{for} \ (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
0 & \text{for} \ (x,y) = (0,0)
\end{cases}
$$
and a point $(x,y) = (rcos(v),rsin(v)$ where $r> 0 $ and $0 \leq v \leq 2 \pi$ I have to find $f(x,y)$ expressed by $r$ and $v$. Does this just mean that I have to replace $(x,y)$ with $rcos(v),rsin(v)$ or what am I supposed to do? By inserting the above I have
$$
f(x,y) = \frac{2rcos(v)rsin(v)}{r^2cos^2v+r^2sin^2(v)}
$$
Is this just it? I recall that expressing something by "something" means that I have to solve for "something". Does this mean I have to solve for $r$ and $v$? Or do I just simplify the above expression? If so I have simplified to $sin(2v)$.

Furthermore I have to find the image under $f$ of the circle $x^2+y^2 = r^2$. I think I have to solve an inequality here but I am not sure which.

Lastly I have to find the image of the set

$$
\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ ||(x,y)|| < \delta \}
$$

Can you help me in the right directions with these? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,you can directly substitute $(x,y)$ by $(rcos(v),rsin(v))$.We will find $f(r,v)=sin(2v)$.

Secondly,$f(r,v)$ is independent with $r$.Therefore,the image of two set that you have mentioned are equal,which is $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Thanks. But what is the reason that we have $f(r,v)$ and not $f(rcos(v),rsin(v))$? Do you mind explaining?

Comment: Because, inherently, a function of $r\cos v$ and $r\sin v$ *is* a function of $r$ and $v$. We are substituting $x$ and $y$ out to make the function simpler

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should complete your computations:$$\frac{2r\cos(\nu)r\sin(\nu)}{r^2\cos^2(\nu)+r^2\sin^2(\nu)}=\sin(2\nu).$$

Answer (score 0):

You got most of the way:
$$\frac{2r\cos(v)r\sin (v)}{r^2\cos(v)+r^2\sin(v)}=\frac{\not{r^2}(2\cos(v)\sin (v))}{\not{r^2}(\cos^2(v)+\sin^2(v)}$$
Then use appropriate identities to simplify